# IE 8 not respecting div width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to get an img and paragraph inside a div with a width of 120px. This works on IE10, Firefox and Chrome. But not on for browsers before IE10. It looks like IE is not respecting the width of the div, which makes elements like paragraph to have a width of 100%.

What should I change here?

```
.menu {

display:inline-block;
display:-moz-inline-stack;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;

height: 120px;
width: 120px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 120px;
}

.menu img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Is the display property meant to to be on the a tags by any chance ?. Posting a fiddle would help us understand what your HTML structure is like.

Comment: Is the `*display:inline;` only a typo in the above example or is this in your code indeed?

Comment: Post your HTML! I think the problem stems from using inline-block on a block level element, which is not well supported in older IE broswers. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f98LL/1/ this is what I'm doing. I don't have css on tags..but I noticed that ie8 add's a "text-align:center" to my main div..

Comment: off topic, but `display:-moz-inline-stack;`.... do you really need to support Firefox v2 users?

Comment: probably not but just to be safe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a width attributes for inline tags such as `<a>` or `<img>`, unless there are forced to block.

Try this:

```
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
}

.menu img {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

OR (if you want an inline-block behavior working in IE7+)

```
.menu a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* IE 7 HACK */
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

.menu img
{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* IE 7 HACK */
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

It will work, however is not a good practice...

In order to set the `<img>` width you have to change html width attribute, this way:

```
<img src="asd.png" alt="image description" width="100" />
```

Comment: this actually works, at least it's respecting the width of the div. Now the inline (inline-block) does not work on ie8/9, it's one div below the other when I would like to have them side by side. Any hints? thank you!

Comment: ok, now i'm going to edit my post with the inline alternative!